# How SQL calculates NEXT_RUN_DATE for a job schedule?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-agent

I have to make a manual calculation of the next run date for a job, can you help me?

Comment: (please don't double-post; be patient)

Comment: (additional detail excised from duplicate): "I have to manually calculate the value of next_run_date based on freq_interval, freq_subday_type, freq_subday_interval, freq_relative_interval, freq_recurrence_factor, etc"

Answer (score 6):

to get the next run date for a job you can use then [sysschedules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178644.aspx) and [sysjobschedules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188924.aspx) tables

check the next_run_date and next_runtime columns from the table [sysjobschedules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188924.aspx)

> next_run_date int Next date on which
>   the job is scheduled to run. The date
>   is formatted YYYYMMDD.
>
> next_run_time int Time at which the
>   job is scheduled to run. The time is
>   formatted HHMMSS, and uses a 24-hour
>   clock.

see this script

```
Select sched.*,jobsched.* FROM msdb.dbo.sysschedules AS sched
inner Join msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules AS jobsched ON sched.schedule_id = jobsched.schedule_id
```

or you can use the [msdb.dbo.sp_help_jobschedule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176046.aspx) stored procedure, to get the same info.

**UPDATE**

if you need calculate manually the next_run_date you must check the  [**sysschedules**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178644.aspx) table and see the freq_interval,  freq_subday_type, freq_subday_interval, freq_relative_interval, freq_recurrence_factor, active_start_date, active_start_time columns to determine the formula.

check this [link](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1622) to see an example of use.

Comment: Yes, but how SQL calculates the value of NEXT_RUN_DATE?

Comment: Do you know the formula?
That's the question.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `msdb.dbo.sp_help_jobschedule` is much better. `sysjobschedules` doesn’t get updated immediately after a schedule change, at least in SQL Server 2012 SP4.

Answer (score 3):

Check this one:

```
SELECT 

    J.NAME JOB, 

    DATEADD(SS,(H.RUN_TIME)%100,DATEADD(N,(H.RUN_TIME/100)%100,DATEADD(HH,H.RUN_TIME/10000,CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),H.RUN_DATE),112))))
    JOB_STARTED,  

    DATEADD(SS,((H.RUN_DURATION)%10000)%100,DATEADD(N,((H.RUN_DURATION)%10000)/100,DATEADD(HH,(H.RUN_DURATION)/10000,DATEADD(SS,(H.RUN_TIME)%100,DATEADD(N,(H.RUN_TIME/100)%100,DATEADD(HH,H.RUN_TIME/10000,CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),H.RUN_DATE),112)))))))
    JOB_COMPLETED,  

    CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),(H.RUN_DURATION)/10000) + ':' + 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),((H.RUN_DURATION)%10000)/100)+ ':' + 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),((H.RUN_DURATION)%10000)%100) RUN_DURATION,

    CASE H.RUN_STATUS 
    WHEN 0 THEN 'FAILED'
    WHEN 1 THEN 'SUCCEEDED'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'RETRY'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'CANCELED'
    WHEN 4 THEN 'IN PROGRESS'
    END RUN_STATUS
    ,CASE S.FREQ_TYPE 
    WHEN  1 THEN 'ONCE'
    WHEN  4 THEN ' DAILY'
    WHEN  8 THEN ' WEEKLY'
    WHEN  16 THEN ' MONTHLY'
    WHEN  32 THEN ' MONTHLY RELATIVE'
    WHEN  64 THEN ' WHEN SQL SERVER'
    ELSE 'N/A' END [FREQ]
    ,CASE 
    WHEN S.NEXT_RUN_DATE > 0 THEN DATEADD(N,(NEXT_RUN_TIME%10000)/100,DATEADD(HH,NEXT_RUN_TIME/10000,CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),NEXT_RUN_DATE),112)))  
    ELSE CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),'19000101'),112) END NEXT_RUN

FROM 

    MSDB..SYSJOBHISTORY H,
    MSDB..SYSJOBS J, 
    MSDB..SYSJOBSCHEDULES S,
    (
    SELECT 
            MAX(INSTANCE_ID) INSTANCE_ID
            ,JOB_ID 
    FROM MSDB..SYSJOBHISTORY GROUP BY JOB_ID
    ) M
WHERE 
    H.JOB_ID = J.JOB_ID 
AND 
    J.JOB_ID = S.JOB_ID 
AND 
    H.JOB_ID = M.JOB_ID 
AND 
    H.INSTANCE_ID = M.INSTANCE_ID

-- IF you want to check all job for today then uncomments below

-- AND 

--     RUN_DATE = (YEAR(GETDATE())*10000) + (MONTH(GETDATE()) * 100) + DAY(GETDATE())
ORDER BY NEXT_RUN
```

Comment: I got errors when running this script. s.freq_type?

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://www.sqlprofessionals.com/blog/sql-scripts/2014/10/06/insight-into-sql-agent-job-schedules/) is a very nice script where you can get the next run date.

```
-- http://www.sqlprofessionals.com/blog/sql-scripts/2014/10/06/insight-into-sql-agent-job-schedules/

SELECT   [JobName] = [jobs].[name]
        ,[Enabled] = CASE [jobs].[enabled] WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END
        ,[Scheduled] = CASE [schedule].[enabled] WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END

        ,[Next_Run_Date] = 
                CASE [jobschedule].[next_run_date]
                    WHEN 0 THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '1900/1/1')
                    ELSE CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), [jobschedule].[next_run_date], 112) + ' ' + 
                         STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [jobschedule].[next_run_time]), 6), 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':'))
                END

        ,[Category] = [categories].[name]
        ,[Owner] = SUSER_SNAME([jobs].[owner_sid])

        ,[Description] = [jobs].[description]
        ,[Occurs] = 
                CASE [schedule].[freq_type]
                    WHEN   1 THEN 'Once'
                    WHEN   4 THEN 'Daily'
                    WHEN   8 THEN 'Weekly'
                    WHEN  16 THEN 'Monthly'
                    WHEN  32 THEN 'Monthly relative'
                    WHEN  64 THEN 'When SQL Server Agent starts'
                    WHEN 128 THEN 'Start whenever the CPU(s) become idle' 
                    ELSE ''
                END
        ,[Occurs_detail] = 
                CASE [schedule].[freq_type]
                    WHEN   1 THEN 'O'
                    WHEN   4 THEN 'Every ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, [schedule].[freq_interval]) + ' day(s)'
                    WHEN   8 THEN 'Every ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, [schedule].[freq_recurrence_factor]) + ' weeks(s) on ' + 
                        LEFT(
                            CASE WHEN [schedule].[freq_interval] &  1 =  1 THEN 'Sunday, '    ELSE '' END + 
                            CASE WHEN [schedule].[freq_interval] &  2 =  2 THEN 'Monday, '    ELSE '' END + 
                            CASE WHEN [schedule].[freq_interval] &  4 =  4 THEN 'Tuesday, '   ELSE '' END + 
                            CASE WHEN [schedule].[freq_interval] &  8 =  8 THEN 'Wednesday, ' ELSE '' END + 
                            CASE WHEN [schedule].[freq_interval] & 16 = 16 THEN 'Thursday, '  ELSE '' END + 
                            CASE WHEN [schedule].[freq_interval] & 32 = 32 THEN 'Friday, '    ELSE '' END + 
                            CASE WHEN [schedule].[freq_interval] & 64 = 64 THEN 'Saturday, '  ELSE '' END , 
                            LEN(
                                CASE WHEN [schedule].[freq_interval] &  1 =  1 THEN 'Sunday, '    ELSE '' END + 
                                CASE WHEN [schedule].[freq_interval] &  2 =  2 THEN 'Monday, '    ELSE '' END + 
                                CASE WHEN [schedule].[freq_interval] &  4 =  4 THEN 'Tuesday, '   ELSE '' END + 
                                CASE WHEN [schedule].[freq_interval] &  8 =  8 THEN 'Wednesday, ' ELSE '' END + 
                                CASE WHEN [schedule].[freq_interval] & 16 = 16 THEN 'Thursday, '  ELSE '' END + 
                                CASE WHEN [schedule].[freq_interval] & 32 = 32 THEN 'Friday, '    ELSE '' END + 
                                CASE WHEN [schedule].[freq_interval] & 64 = 64 THEN 'Saturday, '  ELSE '' END 
                            ) - 1
                        )
                    WHEN  16 THEN 'Day ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, [schedule].[freq_interval]) + ' of every ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, [schedule].[freq_recurrence_factor]) + ' month(s)'
                    WHEN  32 THEN 'The ' + 
                            CASE [schedule].[freq_relative_interval]
                                WHEN  1 THEN 'First'
                                WHEN  2 THEN 'Second'
                                WHEN  4 THEN 'Third'
                                WHEN  8 THEN 'Fourth'
                                WHEN 16 THEN 'Last' 
                            END +
                            CASE [schedule].[freq_interval]
                                WHEN  1 THEN ' Sunday'
                                WHEN  2 THEN ' Monday'
                                WHEN  3 THEN ' Tuesday'
                                WHEN  4 THEN ' Wednesday'
                                WHEN  5 THEN ' Thursday'
                                WHEN  6 THEN ' Friday'
                                WHEN  7 THEN ' Saturday'
                                WHEN  8 THEN ' Day'
                                WHEN  9 THEN ' Weekday'
                                WHEN 10 THEN ' Weekend Day' 
                            END + ' of every ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, [schedule].[freq_recurrence_factor]) + ' month(s)' 
                    ELSE ''
                END
        ,[Frequency] = 
                CASE [schedule].[freq_subday_type]
                    WHEN 1 THEN 'Occurs once at ' + 
                                STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [schedule].[active_start_time]), 6), 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':')
                    WHEN 2 THEN 'Occurs every ' + 
                                CONVERT(VARCHAR, [schedule].[freq_subday_interval]) + ' Seconds(s) between ' + 
                                STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [schedule].[active_start_time]), 6), 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':') + ' and ' + 
                                STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [schedule].[active_end_time]), 6), 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':')
                    WHEN 4 THEN 'Occurs every ' + 
                                CONVERT(VARCHAR, [schedule].[freq_subday_interval]) + ' Minute(s) between ' + 
                                STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [schedule].[active_start_time]), 6), 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':') + ' and ' + 
                                STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [schedule].[active_end_time]), 6), 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':')
                    WHEN 8 THEN 'Occurs every ' + 
                                CONVERT(VARCHAR, [schedule].[freq_subday_interval]) + ' Hour(s) between ' + 
                                STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [schedule].[active_start_time]), 6), 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':') + ' and ' + 
                                STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [schedule].[active_end_time]), 6), 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':')
                    ELSE ''
                END
        ,[AvgDurationInSec] = CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), [jobhistory].[AvgDuration])

FROM     [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs] AS [jobs] WITh(NOLOCK) 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobschedules] AS [jobschedule] WITh(NOLOCK) 
                 ON [jobs].[job_id] = [jobschedule].[job_id] 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN [msdb].[dbo].[sysschedules] AS [schedule] WITh(NOLOCK) 
                 ON [jobschedule].[schedule_id] = [schedule].[schedule_id] 
         INNER JOIN [msdb].[dbo].[syscategories] [categories] WITh(NOLOCK) 
                 ON [jobs].[category_id] = [categories].[category_id] 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                    (   SELECT   [job_id], [AvgDuration] = (SUM((([run_duration] / 10000 * 3600) + 
                                                                (([run_duration] % 10000) / 100 * 60) + 
                                                                 ([run_duration] % 10000) % 100)) * 1.0) / COUNT([job_id])
                        FROM     [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobhistory] WITh(NOLOCK)
                        WHERE    [step_id] = 0 
                        GROUP BY [job_id]
                     ) AS [jobhistory] 
                 ON [jobhistory].[job_id] = [jobs].[job_id];
```